# SQL query error in Python with parameter SQL method occurs during program execution

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to run the following code, but Python gives me an error
code :

```
select = input("ENTER USER FOR PASS RECOVERY :  ")
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_stat WHERE usr=(%s)",(select))
```

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCQDw.png)
error :

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GKLe.png)
In which part of the code is the problem and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `cursor.execute` must be an iterable of params, So you should pass them as:

1. A list: `[select]`
2. A tuple: `(select,` ). Note that passing `(select)` does not make it a tuple.

And another question, which client do you use to connect to MySQL? Some clients use `?` as param placeholders and not `%s`

Answer (score 0):

if you need more examples or more help similar post is here -> [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Also take a look at Kashyap (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734918/2561174) comment with a good/bad query practices, he give this example on how to use it:

```
# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

Wish it helps you!

Answer (score -2):

You have to use {} instead of () 
select = input("ENTER USER FOR PASS RECOVERY :  ")
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_stat WHERE usr={%s}",(select))

Comment: I received the same error again with this move